Why does my Bluetooth speaker keep on connecting and disconnecting?
I have a speaker connected to my Bluetooth, and the Bluetooth keeps connecting then disconnecting as seen in the videos below.
The speaker is a Sony SRS-XP700 and it has worked fine up until a few days ago.
When I look in the device manager it keeps reloading all the devices too on a loop.
I updated my driver to the latest driver (23.x.x.x), but it seems to keep rolling back to 20.x.x.x.
What would be causing this issue what can I do to fix it?
Bluetooth and devices:



The Bluetooth taskbar:




This answer comes from the Microsoft Community forums; it was posted by Hi-P on January 9, 2019:

“For people with the same problem, if none of the answers above worked for you, try completely shutting down the system, I don't mean to just "shut down windows", no, completely, turn off the Power Supply after shutting down the computer then turn it back on, power on the computer and that's it, I don't know why this worked.”

